# Odoo11 - Restrict user assignment to project team members

Tags: project, odoo-11

I downloaded the .exe file of the community edition of odoo 11, installed it on a windows server and configured rules, that projects can only be seen by users who are assigned to the project as team members.
That works fine!

Now, in a task I want to restrict the options in the "assigned to" dropdown of a task: In the dropdown I want to see only users, who are actually assigned to that project. At the moment I can see all existing users and can assign the task to any of them.

In the form view I tried to restrict the list as follows by adding the *domain* attribute:

```
<field name="user_id" class="o_task_user_field" domain="('user_id','in', [project.members])" />
```

This gives an error on save.
**Field 'project' used in attributes must be present in view but is missing**

**Update: 2. approach:**

I tried to update the field *user_id* in model *project.task* and set the *domain* as follows:

```
('project_id.members','in', [user.id])
```

But I got the error (translated from german): *you cannot make changes in a basic field!*

How can I limit the options in the dropdown (without making code changes as I don´t have the code forked from github)?

Any help appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you just need to update one onchange and in that add domain. No need to add it from xml. There is by default `onchange_project`method is there. In that you just inherit it and add one line..

```
result.update({'domain':{'user_id':[('project_ids','in',project_id)]}})
```

Comment: Hi Keval, thanks for the reply. 
I have Odoo installed on a Windows Server and am not sure how I can add the python code via the website?
I believe that I might need to download the code from github, change the python code there and then rebuild the whole application. I hope there is a simpler solution to that. Can you point me in the right direction?
Thanks, Herbert

Comment: No need to change code via website. As you are saying you installed odoo then do you have clone github branch for this ? If yes then you can edit it directly from that branch code.

Comment: No, I didn´t clone the repo from github. Just downloaded the exe file from [here](https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/page/download) and installed it.